# Link NGINX + PHP-FPM on Docker [Using Docker Run]?

Tags: php, docker, nginx

Im trying to run a NGINX + PHP-FPM application but im getting stuck here and there.

I followed this main question here at StackOverFlow: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29905953/how-to-correctly-link-php-fpm-and-nginx-docker-containers)
Went through all comments, made a lot of changes and none of it worked...

Everytime i open a PHP file, my browser downloads its instead of running the script on PHP FPM.

The steps i made are the following:

```
# Create Network
docker network create nginx-php
docker network ls

# Run NGINX and PHP-FPM.
docker run -d -p 9000:9000 --name php-fpm `
 --network=nginx-php `
 -v D:\Docker\Html:/usr/share/nginx/html php:7.4-fpm-alpine

docker run --name nginx -p 80:80 `
 --network=nginx-php `
 -v D:\Docker\Html:/usr/share/nginx/html `
 -v D:\Docker\Config\nginx:/etc/nginx `
 -d nginx:1.23.1-alpine
```

My NGINX Config file:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      listen [::]:80 default_server;
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

      server_name _;

      location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
      }

      location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000; # Nome do container PHP-FPM e onde ele ta hospedado
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params; # Adaptado para Docker
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      }

      location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
      }
    } # End of PHP FPM Nginx config example
}
```

As you can see, the block with PHP-FPM Pass is exactly as the one stated on the question and documentation.

So i really have no idea whats happening, can someone help me?

PS: Just for clarity, you may be wondering why not take the Docker Compose / DockerFile approach, but i am taking this approach because im currently studying docker and do not know how Docker Compose / DockerFile works that well, so i sticky with the basics for now.

**Edit**: I discovered that the problem only occurs to fastcgi_pass using TCP connection to the container. If i copy /run/php/ from PHP-FPM and mount it as a volume on both containers, and use unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock instead of php-fpm:9000 it works... ._.
Yeah, but i would still like to use TCP method instead since its faster to deploy on any computer.

Comment: Compose just takes care of a lot of the boilerplate like network configuration. Highly recommended. Here's a decent LEMP compose stack (you can ignore the database) ~ https://github.com/stevenliebregt/docker-compose-lemp-stack

Comment: I went a little further and it looks like this is using link to make the connection between containers, as of https://docs.docker.com/network/links/ this is a obsolete method... Do you know a alternative?

Comment: You don't need `link` at all. Typically, all containers in a compose stack share a network and can connect using their service names

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For some reason using the "Server Block" in default.conf inside conf.d instead of leaving inside HTTP Block solved the problem...

Really have no idea why, i just tested it to see if it would work and worked.

So, nginx.conf stayed the same (Equals to the original... Without the Server Block) and Default.conf stayed like this:

```
server {
      listen 80 default_server;
      listen [::]:80 default_server;
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

      server_name _;

      location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
      }

      location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000; # Nome do container PHP-FPM e onde ele ta hospedado
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params; # Adaptado para Docker
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      }

      location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
      }
    } # End of PHP FPM Nginx config example
```

Go figure ‍♂️